# How to Use the Function is_user_logged_in To Display Different Menus?

Tags: php, customization, menus

So, I want to create different menus for people who are logged in or not.

I got a reply that i should use a function

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_name_menu(array('theme_location' => 'logged_user' ));
} else {
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'new_user' ));
}
```

So, if I get this right, I put this into `functions.php` which is located in my child theme (anywhere inside the file?), then I create another menu and where it is "logged_user" and "new_user" I enter the names of the menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just did this for a site i am working on.  first i registered 2 menus in functions.php:

```
add_action('init','kia_menus');

function kia_menus(){

    register_nav_menus( array('primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu for Logged In Users', 'kia_theme' ), 
            'primary-loggedout' => __( 'Primary Menu for Logged Out Visitors', 'kia_theme')
                                    ));
}
```

and then where i want the 1 menu to appear based on the user's status (probably in header.php but depends on your theme):

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-loggedout' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
}
```

Comment: so the first part goes to functions.php and the second one to the place where i want the menus to be? In the second part do I have to change theme_location to the location or just leave it like that? And in the first part where it is kia_theme I would have to enter my child themes name which would look like Corporate_theme? I'm sorry for these newbie questions but I have no experience in coding

Comment: yes part 1 goes in functions.php and yes the 2nd part goes where you want to display the menu.  the theme_location can be whatever, but it needs to match what you declared in register_nav_menus.  kia_theme is my text domain for translation purposes. you can make it be anything and if you don't plan to make your theme translatable, you don't need it at all.