# How can I hide the TOP Navigation menu if users are not logged in

Tags: navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [different menus with is_user_logged_in in more detail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44393/different-menus-with-is-user-logged-in-in-more-detail)

how can i hide my top navigation menu to users who are not logged in?

here is the url to the site, its on a password protected dev server so you can use the user & pass below to access the site.

http://chicagodietetic.demotheweb.com

username:  chicagodietetic
password:  demo

Thanks
Aron

Comment: Curiously, your question has all the keywords for the function you are searching for (`is_user_logged_in`). [This Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) will be of great help with your further needs/investigations into WordPress. I'm flagging your Q as duplicate, this topic has already been [covered here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44393/12615). Please read the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), take a look at [this notification apps](http://stackapps.com) and welcome to WPSE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user logged in by calling [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function. Modify your menu rendering call like this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_id() ) : ?>
    <!-- above html related to menu is going here -->
    <?php // wp_nav_menu call ... ?>
    <!-- below html related to menu is going here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Eugene, I was about to answer the question too, but a fast search for `is_user_logged_in` shows lots of duplicates... Not much of a point to answer then... Nonetheless, I'll buy the next round, [*toct!*](http://cl.ly/HCkP)