# Showing A Menu When Only Users Are Logged In

Tags: login, wp-login-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Use the Function is_user_logged_in To Display Different Menus?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44393/how-to-use-the-function-is-user-logged-in-to-display-different-menus)

I wish to create a log in page, that displays like an extended menu for example (the people who land on the page first will not see this extended menu)

Now is it a case that i create a page that uses one menu? And another page that uses a different menu?

However i have used the menu in the header, so would i need to create a different page template that calls one header showing X menu, and then another one that shows Y menu which the customers will be directed to when they "log in"

Thankyou in advance.
Kirsty

Comment: By the way, did you try [**searching the site for related questions**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=different+menu+logged+in) before posting? This one has been asked several times.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`is_user_logged_in()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) conditional to output a different menu depending on user login state. For example:

```
$theme_location = ( is_user_logged_in() ? 'header_logged_in' : 'header_not_logged_in' );

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => $theme_location
);
```